# How to search with whole word in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search, uisearchbar

I have added a search bar with UITableView. when I enter the first character then it search all records starting with that character but when i enter the next character then it search nothing.

Kindly help me. If this is a silly question then kindly be patient and guide me
Thanx

Code

```
-(void)searchData:(NSString*)search{

//    search = [search uppercaseString];

    NSLog(@"Array count233 : %d", [menuArray count]);



    NSLog(@"Array count237 : %d", [menuArray count]);

    NSLog(@"Search String : %@", search);
    if ([search isEqualToString:@""]) {

    }
    else {

        [tableMenuArray removeAllObjects];

            for (int i = 0; i < [menuArray count]; i++) {
                if ([[[menuArray objectAtIndex:i] itemName] hasPrefix:search]) {
                    [tableMenuArray addObject:[menuArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                    NSLog(@"Found");
                }
            }
        }
    [menuTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: your question doesn't contain requested information. what are you searching? from what are you searching? are you are searching from database?

Comment: can you post your search code?

Comment: yes @danh i have added. if u see 2nd line. If I comment it then it search well but it is case sensitive. If I have to search "Salad" then i have to write "Salad" if i write "salad" then it will not search it. and if i uncomment 2nd line then it will find only with first character.

Comment: @DesaiAjay I am searching in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uncomment the 2nd line, then change this line -

```
if ([[[menuArray objectAtIndex:i] itemName] hasPrefix:search])
```

...to -

```
if ([[[[menuArray objectAtIndex:i] itemName] uppercaseString] hasPrefix:search])
```

Otherwise you're comparing all-uppercase to normally-cased words. Hope this sorts it for you!